# How to customize list style?

Tags: lists, enumerate, description, bullets

I am trying to create some lists that are both numbered and lettered. For instance, in one section I would like a list with:

ER-1  description

ER-2 description

ER-3 description

Then in another section I would like different lettering (CR-1, CR-2, etc.). How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  As long as you are consistent within a list, this shouldn't be difficult, although I haven't time just now to dig up the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the `enumitem` package. It adds an optional where you can specify various settings including the label format, with something like `\arabic*` to represent the arabic numeral for the item (similarly `\alph*`, `\Roman*`, etc. could be used instead).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=ER-\arabic*]

\item First list item

\item Second list item \label{mylabel}

\item Third list item

\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=CR-\arabic*]

\item A new list

\item Yet another item

\item Still yet another item

\end{enumerate}

As seen in \ref{mylabel} \ldots

\end{document}
```

[image: lists examples]

See the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for more details.